# Recieve output from a second Python script that I have called from my first Python script

Tags: python, function

I tried to look for an answer to this before I posted it, but I'm having trouble wording it. So, if theres a duplicate question on the site, I apologise.

I have a Commend Line python script (in this example we'll call it Script 1) which calls a function from another script (which we'll call Script 2). I do this by:

```
import Script2
Script2.Some_Function()
```

Some_Function does various things, such as connecting to servers on the internet and performing file look ups. Ordinarily, if one of these tasks failed, it would print an error stating this to the screen:

```
def Some_Function():
   def error(err):
     print "Error: " + err
```

However, when I know an error should be being printed, I'm not seeing anything being printed to the screen. I suspect this is because I'm calling it from Script 1.
Is there anything I can do? I really need the output from Script 2 to be printed.

Comment: FYI, please use the correct terminology: you do not import a *script* but a **module**. A script has a vague definition, and all it usually means is a *"little bit of code to do something in a high level interpreted language"*.

Comment: You could use subprocess

Comment: Padraic, I did initially think of using subprocess and the communicate() function, but I didnt think it would work. I thought that because the error could come at any time while some function is running, when I initially call communicate() there might not be any output.

Comment: when you have two python ***modules***, and you want to use one from the other, there's no reason to use subprocess. You can use the module import model of python and use the symbols of the first in the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your code is exactly like your snippet, it's not likely to work, but first things first, let's use the correct wording, in python you use the term `module` to name another python file containing symbols you want to import in the current (`module`) one.

A script is usually a small piece of code in a high level language that you run from your command line interface. So as a rule of thumb, a script in python is where you put `if __name__ == '__main__':`

So I'm renaming your example:

**myscript.py**:

```
import external_module
external_module.some_function()
```

**external_module**:

```
def some_function():
   def error(err):
       print "Error: " + err
```

> *However, when I know an error should be being printed, I'm not seeing anything being printed to the screen. I suspect this is because I'm calling it from Script 1. Is there anything I can do? I really need the output from Script 2 to be printed.*

now that the code is "cleaned" a bit, when you run your program what is happening?

```
python myscript.py
```

well, nothing, and that's expectable: because you're doing nothing! Let's add comments:

**myscript.py**:

```
import external_module            # you import the module external_module
external_module.some_function()   # you run the function some_function()
                                  # from external_module
```

in myscript nothing's wrong. But your problem is in external_module:

**external_module**:

```
def some_function():              # you declare the function some_function
   def error(err):                # you declare the function error 
                                  # that lives only in some_function() scope
       print "Error: " + err      # in error() you print something out!
```

so, when you do `external_module.some_function()`, you just *declare* the function `error()` and you never run it, which means you never run the `print` statement. If you forget the `import` aspect, and only do in the python REPL:

```
>>> def foo():
...    def bar():
...        print("Hello world?")
...
>>> foo()
>>>
```

it does nothing! But if you do:

```
>>> def foo():
...    def bar():
...        print("Hello World!")
...    bar()            # here you call the function bar() inside foo()
...
>>> foo()
Hello World!
>>>
```

you get to run `bar()`!

I hope that my explanation was exhaustive enough!

HTH

Comment: This is a really good answer, so I will mark it as solved, but it doesnt help me out. I'm going to modify my wording of the question and ask it again.
The issue is, I'm using an external framework called Twisted, which i'm calling from the external module I wrote. When an error is received from that framework (which is produced when it loses connection to a host I have specified) it prints an error, but that print statement isn’t being outputted to the command line where I called the first script.